# How to collect the files with specific keyword in their file names within a directory

Tags: bash, perl, shell, if-statement, for-loop

I have a directory with number of files. My requirement is, I have to search for the file-names(not file data) based on particular keyword and print that filename.

For example

`ABC` is the directory. Below it are files

```
 AEXP/INC/ARP.txt
 AEXP/OPC/ARP.txt
 AEXP/INC/PQW.txt
```

I want the files contains with the keyword `INC`.

Expected output:

```
AEXP/INC/ARP.txt
AEXP/INC/PQW.txt
```

I tried this logic, But it is not working properly

```bash
#!/bin/sh

for FILE in ABC/* do
    if [[ $file =~ /INC/i ]] then
        echo success;
    else
        echo fail;
    fi
done
```

Please help me to get the right answer. bash script, Perl, regex, anything is fine.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and how is it not working for you? Please learn [ask] good questions, how to create a [mcve], and take a [tour] of the site while you're at it to find out how [so] works.

Comment: `perl -E "say for glob 'ABC/*/INC/*.txt'"`

Comment: I tried this logic, But it is not working properly.                                                                                                                         #!/bin/sh
for FILE in ABC/*
do
   if [[ $file =~ /INC/i ]]
   then
    echo success;
   else
    echo fail;
   fi

done

Comment: @Naveen.Y: Doesn't my Perl command do what you want?

Comment: @Borodin - Its working perfect, Just now I've tested. Thanks much

Answer (score 3):

On linux you could use "find". On an Ubuntu shell, this looks like:

```
find . -name "*INC*" -print
```

Comment: Thank you @sal                                                                                                                           But I need this to be performed on particular directory. And also require automated approach, because I have to add this step to the workflow.

Comment: Right. That command can be used inside a bash script, like this:
`list=(`find . -name "*get*" -print`)` and then you can access the whole list as `${list[@]}` and so on...

Comment: To access a particular directory, you just need to `cd <desired directory>` before that step, or provide the path instead of the "." to `find`.

Comment: Yeah.. Got it.. Thanks much @sal

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
cd ABC
ls -d */INC/*
```

Is it necessary that you check also for the uppercase/lowercase variants?

Comment: Yeah.. It is working as I needed. Thanks much @user1934428